# Pegar medidas de um elemento e jogar em variáveis? Como fazer?

Tags: css, sass

Tem algum meio (usando Sass talvez) de pegar as medidas (`width` e/ou `height`) de elementos já definidos e armazená-las em variáveis pra usá-las em cálculos de outros elementos?

Comment: Eu acredito que a lógica seja a inversa: crie variáveis, e aí use para definir as medidas de todos os elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem por javascript. Utilizando jQuery você pode pegar o tamanho de uma `div`, por exemplo, assim:

```
var largura = $('div#id').width();
```

A altura:

```
var altura = $('div#id').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando o framework **YUI 3** a solução é essa:

```
var largura, altura;

YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    largura = Y.one('div#meu-id').getComputedStyle('width');
    altura = Y.one('div#meu-id').getComputedStyle('height');
});
```

Usando **apenas JavaScript** (Chrome, Firefox, Opera e Safari)

```
<style>
  div#meu-id  {
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>

<div id="meu-id">Meu conteúdo</div>

var RefDiv = document.getElementById("meu-id");
var largura = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(RefDiv, null).getPropertyValue("width");
var altura = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(RefDiv, null).getPropertyValue("height");
setTimeout( function() { alert('largura = ' + largura + ', altura = ' + altura); }, 5000);
```

Usei o setTimeout para o caso de haver código que altere o conteúdo do elemento e assim damos um tempo para renderização.